# Add menu in standalone toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to use a standalone toolbar and for that I defined a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in my layout.
I want to add an item in the menu and using `inflateMenu` the toolbar seems to work fine **but** the [inflateMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#inflateMenu(int)) was added in API-21.
How can I add a menu for earlier SDKs?

Comment: You're looking at the docs for the platform `Toolbar` class. The support class will have that method no matter the API level you're running on. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#inflateMenu(int)

Comment: @MikeM.:That is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna add/show menu buttons, why don't you use

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_button1) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the SupportToolbar like the default one, you need to tell your Activity to use it as a normal Toolbar by using

```
Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

After that you can use the Toolbar like a default one with Framework functionalities like onCreateOptionMenu or onOptionsItemSelected.